# Sonata Admin, split one entity (in db) to more display block switch a discrimatory field

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I pass all the day reading, testing, re-reading and re-testing, I can't find a proper solution to my problem.

Let say you have a file entity, which switch type, go to a different block. (I mean, in the database i only have 1 file table, but in the display, i have a block "images", another "documents" and another "map"). All 3 are files with a different value for the field "type".

I know that the simplest should be to have 3 tables but i don't want to ruin my architecture because of using sonata.

I totally figure out how to do it in practice with preupdate and prepersist events and the initialisation phase. But even when i try to give the option "admin_code" to my unmapped property $images. It's always saying that it need an admin class. As the admin class is mapped by the annotation @ORM\OneToMany, i can't use it otherwise doctrine generates me another table.

Is there any way to achieve this ?
Is the admin_code option bugged ?

Or should i pass by a front-end solution? (i totally prefer back-end, but i will do with what is possible)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use [Doctrine inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)

I think you'll be able to create an abstract File class and 3 other classes that extend File :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"image" = "Image", "document" = "Document", "map" = "Map"})
 */
abstract class File {
    ...
}
```

Then you'll have to create the 3 classes:

```
class Image extends File {
    ...
}


class Document extends File {
    ...
}


class Map extends File {
    ...
}
```

After, you'll be able to create 3 differents admin class to display in Sonata.

Comment: Hi,

Yes i tried, it was a good option, but my discriminatory field is an entity so i can't get it work.

I was wondering to put this field in string and manage it in php not in entity, so i can try the discriminatoryField but my CTO is came today and says, it's too late do 3 entities.... :'(

But i created a branch with my code of yesterday, and i will try inheritance, as soon as i have 5 minutes for my personal understanding.

And also i will come to close this ticket as soon as i get it working ;)

Thanks for your answer.